# Ruby sort an array in ascending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sorting

I have an array  `['f_1', 'f_10', 'f_3', 'f_2']`

I want to sort this array in ascending order using ruby one line code.

Comment: why ask a question when you have found the answer???

Comment: Why would you mark your own question as a duplicate? Lol

Answer (score 3):

Do as below using [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by) :

```
['f_1', 'f_10', 'f_3', 'f_2'].sort_by {  |s| s[/\d+/].to_i }
# => ["f_1", "f_2", "f_3", "f_10"]
```